# How should I implement authorization in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, laravel-authorization

I implemented authorization in laravel 5.3 successfully. But in Laravel 5.6 Policy method such as index, view, ... doesnt work and Laravel doesnt call these methods on policy. why?

Controller:

```
public function index($member)
{
   $this->authorize(Time::find($member));
   ...
}
```

AuthServiceProvider:

```
 protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
        Time::class => TimePolicy::class,
    ];
```

TimePolicy:

```
  public function index(User $user, Time $time)
    {
        if ($time->member_id == $user->id)
            return true;
    }

    public function view(User $user, Time $time)
    {
        if ($time->member_id == $user->id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Why Laravel 5.6 doesn't call related Policy method?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `$this->authorize('index', Time::find($member));`

Comment: No it doesn't work, Problem happened for all policies when i upgraded from Laravel 5.3 to 5.6

Comment: Do you get any error or the method call is simply ignored?

Comment: @Helder Lucas method call is simply ignored and 403 error will be thrown.

Comment: @Helder Lucas problem resolved. It was a forgotten code!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to use Model namespaces at top of `AuthServiceProvider`. Problem resolved ;)